# Unreal Engine 5 Blueprint: Creating directories during runtime

Tags: directory, path, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I wanna store a json file within a specific location on the user's computer, and I found a way to do that with the Json Blueprint Utilities plugin.

Whenever I try to store it within an unexisting path, instead of creating the path and creating the json within it, it simply does neither. If the path exists however, it creates the json just fine. In itself that isn't a major problem since I can just create the missing path before creating the json file... oh wait... How am I supposed to do that?

I've been looking *everywhere* and anywhere and found *nothing*! The only thing is a "Make Directory" blueprint node, which doesn't show up when I type it in any Event Graph (I'm using a widget specifically but nothing else seemingly works).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Make Directory' node is in the 'Blueprint File Utilities' plugin.

This is a built-in plugin that you just need to enable in the plugins window.

It is a little annoying that the [documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/BlueprintAPI/FileUtils/) doesn't say that you need to enable the plugin.

Comment: i love you, im still quitting stack overflow, but i love you

Comment: Why are you quitting? Stay!